# How to use the VideoView .isPlaying() method?

Tags: java, android

My Aim is to play a repeating animation for the duration the video is played, as I am using a VideoView I thought that I might as well take advantage of the .isPlaying method to resolve implement this **however the while loop does not execute at all**

```
    Floater0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Floater0);
    AdPlayer0 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.AdPlayer);

    ConvertedSource = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.kitkat);
    AdPlayer0.setVideoURI(ConvertedSource);
    AdPlayer0.start();

    while (AdPlayer0.isPlaying()){
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(answer,  answer, 0,  height * -1); // xfrom , xto, y from,y to
        animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration influences the speed of full execution
        Floater0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show it
        Floater0.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation

    }
```

The video plays successfully but animations do not appear, I have made sure that the animation is implemented and having correctly simply by placing it out side the braces of the loop, however this is not the aim as I want to repeatedly play animations when the video is played!

Comment: You can stat the loop animation in same time as the video, and in the videoView onCompletionListner, just stop your animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(answer,  answer, 0,  height * -1); // xfrom , xto, y from,y to
animation.setDuration(5000);
Floater0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show it
Floater0.startAnimation(animation);
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (AdPlayer0.isPlaying()) {
        Floater0.startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

for your video view use setOnCompletionListener for find out to video finish playing. Inside this listener stop the animation and hide the  Floater0.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1):

```
 AdPlayer0.start();

 while (AdPlayer0.isPlaying()){
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(answer,  answer, 0,  height * -1); // xfrom , xto, y from,y to
        animation.setDuration(5000);  // animation duration influences the speed of full execution
        Floater0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show it
        Floater0.startAnimation(animation);  // start animation

    }
```

Maybe the video don't have time to load, after the start your are directly calling the while, but isPlaying should return false maybe as the video is not started yet. Moreover in your while block your creating a new animation, it will result to create multiple animation when the video is still playing...

Comment: Good point, but how do I buy more time, do you think dindinii answer bought me the time I need?

Comment: Yes the dindinii soulution is perfect

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to remove the while (AdPlayer0.isPlaying()){

add `animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);`

and on

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        Floater0.stopAnimation(animation);
}
```

Comment: sorry one detail I left out is that I am dynamical changing the parameters of the animation, therefore simply repeating the animation wont do!

Comment: so sorry I didn't know that.